# How to cut specifics parts of a line with Python?

Tags: python-3.x, printing, debian, fail2ban

I'm trying to make a script that **display** recent Ban, Found or Unban infos that are in fail2ban logs (/var/log/fail2ban), but I want to **hide** this selection for all lines  :

*,325 fail2ban.actions        [424]: NOTICE  [sshd]*

In order to have this :

**2022-07-02 18:15:17 Unban 192.168.200.20**

And not this :

*2022-07-02 18:15:17,325 fail2ban.actions        [424]: NOTICE  [sshd] Unban 192.168.200.20*

Here is my code :

```
with open('/var/log/fail2ban.log', 'r') as f:
     for line in f.readlines():
             if 'Ban' in line:
                   print(line)

             if 'Unban' in line:
                    print(line)

             if 'Found' in line:
                    print(line)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use replace function .

```
with open('/var/log/fail2ban.log', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
            line = line.replace('that string you dont want', '')
            if 'Ban' in line:
                  print(line)
            if 'Unban' in line:
                   print(line)
            if 'Found' in line:
                    print(line)
```